# Как правильно согласовать

Tags: грамотная-речь

ООО в  лице исполнительного директора Ивановой Ирины Ивановны, **действующей (действующего)** на основании
т.е. что главнее м.р. слова директор или Женское имя?

Answer (score 2):

"В разговорной речи частотно использование смыслового (а не грамматического) согласования при существительных мужского рода, характеризующих лиц женского пола: *врач пришла; профессор сказала; директор школы уволилась.*

Однако в официальной речи замена грамматического согласования смысловым не допускается, за исключением тех случаев, когда такое существительное имеет при себе имя собственное, например: *врач Петрова*. В таких конструкциях определение и сказуемое согласуются с ближайшим существительным. Например: *Опытный врач Петрова внимательна к больным*. **Определение-причастие всегда согласуется с именем собственным: *вошедшая в палату врач Петрова*.**

Если подлежащее – собственное имя – имеет при себе обособленное приложение, выраженное нарицательным существительным, то сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим: *Мария Ивановна, учитель математики, заболела*" ([Л. В. Балашова. В. В. Дементьев. Курс русского языка](http://www.licey.net/russian/culture/3_3)).

Примерно то же самое можно прочитать в [Справочнике по правописанию и стилистике](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/147/Род_названий_лиц_женского_пола_по_профессии,_должности_и_т._д.) Розенталя.

Answer (score 1):

Можно посмотреть конкретный договор:

ООО "Стройинвест", именуемое в дальнейшем "Покупатель", в лице Финансового директора Ивановой Ирины Владимировны, действующей на основании Доверенности..."

Answer (score 0):

директор главнее:)Слово действующий согласуется здесь именно со словом директор, а "Ивановой Ирины Ивановны" является определением в слову директор.

Answer (score 0):

Кого директор главнее? Ивановой Ирины Владимировны? Я считаю, что если договор составляется на русском языке, то и должен соответствовать, в первую очередь, правилам русского языка. А по-русски правильно будет так, как написано выше.

*...в лице Финансового директора Ивановой Ирины Владимировны, действующей на основании Доверенности...*